# How to apply ReliableSqlConnection's retry policy on SqlDataAdapter/DataSet

Tags: c#, ado.net, dataset, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-6

We applied Microsoft's Enterprise Library [Transient Fault Handling Block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680899(v=pandp.50).aspx) on the Azure Sql connection and commands.

For example,

```
using(var sqlConnection = new ReliableSqlConnection(_connectionString, _connectionRetry, _commandRetry)
{
    var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "...";
    sqlConnection.Open();

    using(var reader = sqlConnection.ExecuteCommand<SqlDataReader>(command))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

It would work for such as `command.ExecuteReader()`, which is the original call without retry policy. But what if the code uses `DataSet` and `SqlDataAdapter`:

```
using(var sqlConnection = new ReliableSqlConnection(_connectionString, _connectionRetry, _commandRetry)
{
    var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "...";
    sqlConnection.Open();

    // how to convert below codes to right way?
    var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    var dataSet = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(dataSet);

    // handle dataSet
    ...
}
```

We are mainly working on some legacy code to add some retry strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found a solution for this:

```
using(var sqlConnection = new ReliableSqlConnection(_connectionString, _connectionRetry, _commandRetry)
{
    var command = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "...";
    sqlConnection.Open();

    var dataReader = sqlConnection.ExecuteCommand<SqlDataReader>();
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Load(dataReader);

    // handle dataTable, in our case the data set only returns one table, so it's ok
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for _connectionRetry, _commandRetry